# Regex to find match excluding a forward slash in string

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I would like to match some urls that share certains patterns, and include those with only 3 forward slashes. For example:

Pass:

```
abc.org/top/1010/red-shirt-plus
abc.org/top/1567/gree-0109
```

Fail:

```
abc.org/top/1567/gree-0109/size
abc.org/bottoms/1567/red-skirt-plus
```

I try `abc\.org\/top\/[0-9]+\/(.*)$` but it finds no match.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
abc\.org\/top\/[0-9][^\/]+\/[^\/]+$
```

It will match:

```
abc.org/top/1010/red-shirt-plus
abc.org/top/1567/gree-0109
```

But not:

```
abc.org/top/1567/gree-0109/size
abc.org/bottoms/1567/red-skirt-plus
```